# tableView.reloadData() ends other animations, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a todolist with nice animation when I delete a row by right swipe:

```
func toDoItemDeleted(toDoItem: ToDoItem) {
    let index = (toDoItems as NSArray).indexOfObject(toDoItem)
    if index == NSNotFound { return }

    // could removeAtIndex in the loop but keep it here for when indexOfObject works
    toDoItems.removeAtIndex(index)

    // use the UITableView to animate the removal of this row
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    let indexPathForRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForRow], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    // refresh gradient effect of rows
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

So basically I delete data, then make a remove animation with `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForRow], withRowAnimation: .Fade)`, then I decide to fix the gradient effect of all existing rows(background color of rows, up to bottom from red to yellow, deleting a row breaks the gradient effect) by calling `reloadData()`.

The result is `reloadData()` happens too quickly before fade animation even begins, thus kills the animation. My questions are:
1. Why?
2. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use animation block to achieve this one. Try this one :-

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0,
            options: [], animations: {
              toDoItems.removeAtIndex(index)
              // use the UITableView to animate the removal of this row
              tableView.beginUpdates()
              let indexPathForRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
              tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForRow], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
              tableView.endUpdates()
             // refresh gradient effect of rows

            }, completion: { _ in
               tableView.reloadData()
          })
```

Set duration as you want.( 0.3 or what you want )

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple - you are deleting the row with animation, that takes time, usually around .3 secs, but, calling the `reloadData` forces the table to immediately redraw its' contents, which stops the unfinished animations. You could

1) just wait for half a sec to reload your table with `dispatch_after` or something similar;

2) delete the corresponding data from the data source, and reload the table's section with animation using `reloadSections:
withRowAnimation:` without manually deleting the cell;

3) or, leave it, don't reload table if it's not crucial with other leftover cells.

Comment: I've tried `tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .None)`, animation still overlays each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend at the same time you're calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths on the one row you hope to delete, you can also call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths on all of the other remaining index paths.

```
func reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [NSIndexPath],
           withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

What this would do is have the UITableView's Data Source request cellForRowAtIndexPath for all of the remaining index paths.

Cool stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried, still some part of the animation overlays each other. btw, I'm still curious why `reloadData()` breaks the animation, do you care to explain?